# Using the ClientSession object from aiohttp in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp, python-telegram-bot

I don't want to create sessions for every HTTP request in python-telegram-bot.
I can create a ClientSession object in main(), even though a warning is issued against doing so. Also, I'm not closing this session anywhere. Please advise on the correct approach.

```py
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler

app_storage = {}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app_storage['session'] = ClientSession()
    application = Application.builder().token(some_token).build()
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', wake_up))
    application.run_polling()
```

****Solved** (thanks [CallMeStag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10606962/callmestag))**

```py
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler


async def some_name(update, context):
    async with context.bot_data['client'].get(some_url) as response:
        data = await response.json()
        # Some other code


async def post_init(application: Application) -> None:
    application.bot_data['client'] = ClientSession()


async def post_shutdown(application: Application) -> None:
    await application.bot_data['client'].close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = Application.builder().token(some_token).post_init(
        post_init).post_shutdown(post_shutdown).build()
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('some_command', some_name))    
    application.run_polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the object in [`Application.bot_data`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application.bot_data) and access it in every callback via [`context.bot_data`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackcontext.html#telegram.ext.CallbackContext.bot_data) - see also [this wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Storing-bot%2C-user-and-chat-related-data). You might also be interested in the customization of the `context` argument via [`ContextTypes`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.contexttypes.html). If you want to close the session on shutdown, you may want to use [`ApplicationBuilder.post_shutdown`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.applicationbuilder.html#telegram.ext.ApplicationBuilder.post_shutdown).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.